# TypeScript Array.splice deleting wrong entry

Tags: typescript

So, i have an array with messages:
**Example:**

```
author: "63aea86fe37c6b1242a6970a"
chatid: "63aea8c5e37c6b1242a6973f"
files: Array [ "http://localhost:3000/CDN/attachments/63aea8c5e37c6b1242a697…37c6b1242a6970a/20230105124217/photo_2022-11-10_19-02-43.jpg" ]
message: "message"
msgid: "63b6c5a9848cd21d81863f95"
pfp: "http://localhost:3000/CDN/pfp/default.png"
sent_at: "Thu Jan 05 2023 13:42:17 GMT+0100 (közép-európai téli idő)"
username: "Alms"
```

And when i use messages *(the array's name)*.find :

```
let foundMsg = await this.messages.find((msg: any) => msg.msgid === msgid);
```

Then i delete the found message with splice:

```
this.messages.splice(foundMsg, 1);
```

Then it always removes the first entry of the array. Can you tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: [`.splice(start, deleteCount)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) -> `start`: _"Zero-based index at which to start changing the array"_, `deteleCount`: _"**An integer** indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from `start`."_

Comment: `await` is superfluous because `.find()` is not an asynchronous operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` will return the *element*, not the *index*. Use `findIndex` instead, but don't forget to check for the not-found index, `-1` -

```js
const index = this.messages.findIndex(m => m.msgid == msgid)
if (index != -1)
  this.messages.splice(index, 1)
```

If you fail to do this check, `splice` will remove the last element from the array in the event the `msgid` is not found.

Note `find` and `findIndex` are synchronous so you do not need to `await`

Answer (score 1):

`splice` takes an index, don't use `find()` but `findIndex()`.

Comment: That's a comment and a "just a typo" close vote (because reading the documentation would have helped)